# Are Postgres queries blocking?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm quite new to databases... On Postgres, if one connection is running a query that takes a long time, does it block other connections from running queries while that query is still running? I'm referring to Reads.

And what about Writes? Are Writes blocking?

Thanks

Comment: In Postgres, readers never block writers and writers never block readers. More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html

Comment: I see, but reads can block reads, and writes can block writes?

Comment: No reads will never block other reads. And only concurrent writes to the same row will be blocked (connection 1 can update row with id=1 and connection 2 can update row with id=2)

Comment: But, if you use transactions, you can set its isolation levels too http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html

Answer (score 0):

There are certain DDL commands like alter that holds lock. It will block running queries if it applies on large table. Pg_bulkload tool also acquire locks.

For monitoring your current blocking query, please refer the below link :-

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring